# What is the javascript `_|_`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I was looking through a solution to a problem in javascript, namely parsing a string into its constituent names, operators, and brackets, when I saw this expression:

```
return accept(")") ? _|_ : e;
```

What is that `_|_`? Is that using node's `_` feature? I've looked for documentation but not found any.

When I try using it myself, this happens:

```
> 5
5
> true ? _|_ : 0
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at eval:1:1
    at eval
    at n.<anonymous>
```

As a clarification, the variable `_` was not defined anywhere in the code.

This was run on Node v8.1.3, but also works fine on chrome native browser JS.

Here is the code:

```
function tokenise(string) {
  const tokens = string.match( /[a-z]+|\(|\)|[!#$%&*+\-\/<=>@^_.,;]+/gi ) || [];
  const accept = s => s===tokens[0] && tokens.shift() ;
  const unaccept = s => s!==tokens[0] && tokens.shift() ;
  const singles = (e) => ( e = unaccept(")") ) ? [ e, ...brackets() ] : [] ;
  const brackets = (e) => accept("(") ? ( e = brackets(), accept(")") || _|_ , [ e, ...brackets() ] ) : singles() ;
  try      { let e = brackets(); return accept(")") ? _|_ : e ; }
  catch(_) { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_|_` has no special meaning in JavaScript, it's just a `|` ([bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)) expression with the identifier `_` on both sides of it.

That code checks the result of calling `accept` and, if it's truthy, returns the result of the `|` operation; if not it returns the value of `e`.

> Is that using node's `_` feature?

`_` isn't special in Node code. In the REPL (only), it's a variable that receives the result of the most recently evaluated expression; [details here](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_assignment_of_the_underscore_variable).

> As a clarification, the variable `_` was not defined anywhere in the code.

That means that if `accept(")")` returns a truthy value, the code will throw a `ReferenceError` because `_` is an undeclared identifier. If that's what the author intended, there's no need for the `|` operator at all, but in a now-deleted answer, georg pointed out that they *may* have used `_|_` as an attempt to express the mathematical concept of [bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom) ("a computation which never completes successfully"), the symbol for which is `⊥`. In any case, the author seems to use it to force an exception in an expression context (since `throw` is a statement; there's talk of possibly allowing it in expression contexts at some point, though).

Comment: @Xufox: Huh, that's too bad. I've added the gist of what he'd pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

It take a variable `_` and uses a [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) with itself.

As result, you get a 32 bit integer number.

Comment: `_` was not given a value in the code. This is why it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been explained here in details, that your code is quite regular JavaScript, with nothing special about it...

I've come across similar code in more than one programming language when the syntax verbosity was used to generate supposedly funny expressions that resemble Text Art, aka ASCII Art, ones that while make the code look weird, are also 100% valid code.

Your code example reminds one of those stupid jokes, just like when someone introduces a function with a paragraph-long name.